# Functional Search Bar in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, searchbar

I have created a Material UI search bar front-end but for now I am unable to type anything into it. How could I fix this?

```
export default class userSearchPage extends Component <{}, { searchItem: string}>{
  constructor(props: Readonly<{}>) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchItem: 'ha'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
  <div>
    <PermanentDrawerLeft></PermanentDrawerLeft>
    <div className='main-content'>
      {/* <Typography>{this.state.searchItem}</Typography> */}
      <SearchBar

        onChange={e => {
          this.setState({searchItem: e.target.value})
        }}             

        onRequestSearch={() => console.log('onRequestSearch')}
        style={{
          margin: '0 auto',
          maxWidth: 800
        }}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}
}
```

The onChange method doesn't work and gives an error.

I feel that this method in general is not the ideal way. How else could I make the search bar functional in Typescript so it could read and store what the user types in?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<form onSubmit={props.onRequestChange}>
  <input id="searchbartext" onChange={props.onChange} />
</form>
```

Comment: I still get the same error on searchbartext and return along with this one at onChange now: ```Type '(arg0: Event) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'arg0' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>' is missing the following properties from type 'Event': cancelBubble, composed, returnValue, srcElement, and 7 more.```

Comment: { onChange: (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void; onRequestChange: (arg0: any) => any; style: React.CSSProperties | undefined; }